# How to limit mongo query in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to retrieve data from mongodb with python. My db contains lots of data. So I want to limit the data while retrieving. I tried

```
import datetime
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('localhost',27017)
db = connection['MyWork']


db_data = db.myusers.find().limit(2)
#db_data = db.myusers.find()[0:2]
print db_data
print db_data.count()
print db_data[0]
print db_data[1]
print db_data[2]
```

But I am getting more than two documents when I tried above. I am using `pymongo` driver. How to limit the values

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000000000267D518>
3
{u'age': 24.0, u'_id': ObjectId('552b6e90aad3e2d909d5fb28'), u'place': u'Ravipadu', u'name': u'Shiva'}
{u'age': 28.0, u'_id': ObjectId('552b6eabaad3e2d909d5fb29'), u'place': u'Rajahmundry', u'name': u'Anil'}
{u'age': 30.0, u'_id': ObjectId('552b6ec1aad3e2d909d5fb2a'), u'place': u'Manchili', u'name': u'Kishore'}
```

Comment: Have you tried [**`db.myusers.find()[0:2]`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.__getitem__)? This will return this cursor with a limit of 2 and skip of 0 applied.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14712402/2327328

Comment: @ForceBru, Ya tried but still getting all the values

Comment: @philshem, I have gone through that link dear.But i din't get the solution.

Comment: Please post more code. `limit` is supposed to work in this way. There might be problem in somewhere else.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712402/pymongo-cursor-limit1-returns-more-than-1-result), indexed access will ignore the `limit`. And `count()` does not obey limit or skip by default as explained the [manual](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count). You can pass `with_limit_and_skip=True` to make `count()` work with limit.

```
print db_data.count(with_limit_and_skip=True)
```

Or you can iterate the cursor to see limit in effect.

```
for data in db.myusers.find().limit(2):
    print data
```

Comment: Does limit return a list or a generator/cursor?

Answer (score 11):

`db.myusers.find(limit=2)`

If you want to apply some condition, you can use `db.myusers.find({query}, limit=2)` and to count the number of results, use `db.myusers.find({query}, limit=2).count()`

Comment: Bizzarely, this doesn't seem to work if `limit` is a variable of type `int` ?

Comment: If you want to query with a limit, apparently you need to use `limit=limit`. For example: `myusers.find({'name':'myname'}, limit=limit)` where `limit=10000` for example